# Spaces in javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about putting spaces in an alert? When I try to put a space in the alert message the alert just won't appear.

Works - https://jsfiddle.net/yczrhztg/

Doesn't Work - https://jsfiddle.net/6qvuLd93/

Code: `<p onclick=alert("With Or Without Spaces")>Alert me</p>`

Comment: [Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I did that the first time I tested the code but it didn't work then either because dumb as I am I used the same quotes twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just surround attribute value with quotes and escape your string:

```
<p onclick="alert('Doesn\'t work')">Alert me</p> <!-- now it works -->
```

Comment: Argh! I feel so dumb! I did surround the attribute with quotes at first, but I used the same quotes I used for the alert and therefor it didn't work either even without spaces so I removed them..

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
<p onclick="alert('With Or Without Spaces')">Alert me</p>
```

It's not the spaces.  It's the incorrect quoting.